# Advice on getting JSON output from Python code onto single line

Tags: python, json

Hello I am working on a custom integration and to pull in passenger data and current its outputting the JSON on multiple lines and I need it to output on a single line but not sure where I'm going wrong with the code.

```python
# Max pool size
match = re.search('Max pool size : (\d+)', out)
if match:
    stats['Max pool size'] = int(match.group(1))
self.checks_logger.debug('{"name": "passenger-status", "protocol_version": "1", "integration_version": "1.0.0", "metrics": [{ "event_type": "PassengerSample", "Max pool size": "%s",' % stats['Max pool size'])

# App groups
match = re.search('App groups    : (\d+)', out)
if match:
    stats['App groups'] = int(match.group(1))
self.checks_logger.debug('"App groups": "%s",' %
        stats['App groups'])

# Processes
match = re.search('Processes     : (\d+)', out)
if match:
    stats['Processes'] = int(match.group(1))
self.checks_logger.debug('"Processes": "%s",' %
        stats['Processes'])

# Requests in top-level queue
match = re.search('Requests in top-level queue : (\d+)', out)
if match:
    stats['Requests in top-level queue'] = int(match.group(1))
self.checks_logger.debug('"Requests in top-level queue": "%s",' %
        stats['Requests in top-level queue'])

# Requests in queue
match = re.search('Requests in queue: (\d+)', out)
if match:
    stats['Requests in queue'] = int(match.group(1))
self.checks_logger.debug('"Requests in queue": "%s"}]}' %
        stats['Requests in queue'])

return stats

def run(self):
stats = {}
stats.update(self.get_passenger_status())
return stats

if __name__ == "__main__":
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("Passenger")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
passenger = Passenger(None, logger, None)
passenger.run()
```

When I run the executable file the output I receive is:

```json
{“name”: “passenger-status”, “protocol_version”: “1”, “integration_version”: “1.0.0”, “metrics”: [{ “event_type”: “PassengerSample”, “Max pool size”: “4”,
“App groups”: “1”,
“Processes”: “2”,
“Requests in top-level queue”: “0”,
“Requests in queue”: “0”}]}
```

The output I need is:

```json
{“name”: “passenger-status”, “protocol_version”: “1”, “integration_version”: “1.0.0”, “metrics”: [{ “event_type”: “PassengerSample”, “Max pool size”: “4”, “App groups”: “1”, “Processes”: “2”, “Requests in top-level queue”: “0”, “Requests in queue”: “0”}]}
```

Comment: use `json.dumps(dict)`

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't matter whether you have your properties printed out across multiple lines or a single line, nor does the order of the elements matter. Having said that,

```
json.dumps(json.loads(stats))
```

Should do the trick without you having to write a custom parser.